# Can't see the need/use for "die" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, relative-clause

English:

> People pay this man so that he can solve the problems they have with their cars.

Deutsch:

> Leute bezahlen diesen Mann, damit er die Probleme, ***die*** sie mit ihren Autos haben, löst.

What does "***die***" mean in this sentence?

If it means "that", then why don't we use "das" or "dass" instead?

Comment: Funny enough, just the other day we had a similar question. http://german.stackexchange.com/q/33648/1224

Comment: Because that is the German relative pronoun for feminine nouns and not *dass.*

Comment: @Jan: Das Problem, das sie haben - die Probleme, die sie haben. Eine Frage des Plurals, nicht?

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, Plural. Der Rest des Kommentars gilt weiterhin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a relative pronoun that refers back to *die Probleme* (hence *die*, and not *das*). You could replace it with *welche* without changing the meaning. It is the same as the following English equivalent:

> People pay this man so that he can solve the problems, **which** they have with their cars.

It is *die* (and not *das*) because the accusative plural of *das Problem* is *die Probleme*. And it can never be *dass*, because *dass* never introduces a relative clause.

German doesn't offer the possibility to omit the relative pronoun the way English does in your example sentence.